# unity theming flaw

Tags: unity, themes, gtk3

I am using a unity theme called 'Flatttice' installed from noobslabs ppa. The problem with theme is the selected background color and selected foreground color are same for inactive windows. This is causing the selected text in inactive windows invisible. What is the correct unity param that I should edit to correct this.

I've done some homework on theming but am still unable to find the solution.